# Menu Model Item in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x

Does anyone know how can I get the current menu model in Joomla 4?
In 2.5/3.X I was using this code:

```
    $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'MenusModelItem' )
            ->getItem();
```

But this is not working anymore in 4. I kinda cannot find any way to get it in J4.

Regards,
Radek

Answer (score 4):

To get Menu item in Joomla 4 you can get the Item From the Factory like

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$menu = Factory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
```

getActive() will give the curent Menu Item, you can use other methods getDefault() or getItem() as per your need.

You can get Menu items with menu type as

```
$items = $menu->getItems('menutype', 'mainmenu');
```